# Why did Winston shoot?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum

I watched *John Wick: Chapter 3 - Parabellum* and the ending scene where Winston shot John left me in confusion. What was the reason behind shooting John?

Isn't it true that Winston and john planned this shooting because how can john survive if Winston actually meant to shoot John?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## To save & keep the Continental

Winston makes it very clear that he effectively betrays John Wick because the High Table will otherwise kill him.

He makes the deal to keep the Continental and run it as he wishes.

[**CinemaBlend**](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2472197/john-wick-3-is-there-more-to-that-ending-twist-than-meets-the-eye)

> However, regarding that latter one and the following battle at the Continental, Winston declared that this had all been a show of strength, indicating that he wasn’t so much interested in helping John, but wanted to show The High Table he’s still not to be trifled with.
>
> Even if Winston is more fond of John Wick than most people in this colorful underworld, he might not be willing to risk this friendship if it means losing The Continental. So when it came down to choosing one or the other, he chose keeping control of his hotel, and that meant John had to go.

Of course, it *could* all be a ruse but we'll have to wait for Chapter 4 to find out.

Comment: In my opinion, Winston and john planned that scene to save john from the high table. Because Winston didn't try to kill John. Instead of going for his head, Winston went for John's bulletproof suit jacket, allowing him to survive the fall.

Comment: @AymanAmjad Bowery King: *...Are you pissed John?*, John(turns his head over): *Yeah!*